# What is the difference between bash and -bash?

Tags: bash

What is the difference between bash and -bash. When I execute `echo $0`, it returns `bash` on one machine and `-bash` on the other machine. What is the difference between them?

Comment: I think it's only a matter of formatting the output. As far as I know, there's no such thing as a `-bash` shell, but I could be mistaken of course.

Comment: $0 is only the name of the command _by convention._ And another convention is for a login shell to have `-` in front of its name in $0. If you look at [man exec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) you'll see that you can make $0 be anything you like when you execute bash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Processes with a `-` at the beginning of arg 0 have been run via `login`, or by `exec -l` in bash.

Comment: Thanks :) After reading your answer, I did `help exec` and that reads, `If the first argument is '-l', then place a dash in the zeroth arg passed to FILE, as login does.`